# How do I force a specific UIInterfaceOrientation on an individual view in a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, orientation

Okay, so here's the situation:

I have an app in which I only want ONE specific view in a UINavigationController to have a landscape orientation. This view is a UIImageView that I'm capturing a signature on (THAT part works awesome). So, like this:

```
previous view --> signature view --> next view
 (portrait)        (landscape)       (portrait)
```

I can't seem to find a good way to force the device orientation to landscape on that signature screen. It'll never make sense to have a portrait orientation on the signature view because there's really not adequate room for signing in that screen width.

So, any bright ideas on how to accomplish this? I've considered possibly doing the signature view modally, thus breaking out of the navigation controller. Thoughts?

Comment: The project was terminated for budget reasons before I had a chance to work it out. If any answer sounds as though it's along the lines of what I was looking for, it's Epic_orange's and mdizzle's answers of using the view transform strategy. Nirma's solution is the standard fare that everyone seems to respond with. However, this doesn't work with desirable results in the context of a UINavigationController. Try it: setup a UINav with three views...make the second one ALWAYS landscape. Can't accept an answer because I haven't verified, and probably won't. Too busy with ASP.NET MVC these days.

Answer (score 9):

You can try to force Device to rotate to necessary orientation - but you need to handle it manually (in addition to overriding UIViewController orientation handling methods).

To rotate device you can use next methods:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

But in it may not work in all situations...

Also available undocumented approach:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:")
                                       withObject:(__bridge id)((void*)UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)];
```

Comment: Did you get this to work in a UINavigationViewController?  When I do it, it rotates the status bar but not the controller.

Answer (score 6):

Just override this UIViewController method to only return true for landscape like so and the iphone will be forced to rotate to that device orientation, since it has no other option.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: This only works if the UIViewController is not part of a navigation controller.  You have to put this code in the UINavigationController and check to see if the topViewController is the one you in landscape.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, all root UIViewControllers inside of a Navigation Controller must support any of their child orientations.  This means that the first view controller in your setup must support landscape, otherwise the child will only support portrait.

The best way to implement what you are looking for is to create a UIViewController that displays its content view on a rotated transform, and just default all UIViewControllers in that stack to portrait.

Comment: How do you implement *displays its content view on a rotated transform*? Do you have an example for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can embed this view inside a view controller and overwrite the ShouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation method.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To use a View in only landscape, I have the following in the ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't FORCE the view to an orientation. It's a goofy problem. When you're in the context of a UINavigationController, strange things happen in regards to the view layour and the status bar orientation. I never got to the bottom of this, but didn't really care either because the project was cancelled for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for.

```
// Rotates the view.
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159/2);
self.view.transform = transform;

// Repositions and resizes the view.
CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(-80, 80, 480, 320);
self.view.bounds = contentRect;
```

from http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1394-landscape-uiviewcontroller-uiview-rotation.html

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that has landscape only views that even starts in landscape. This was working fine in iOS 5.x but stopped working in iOS 6.x

After trying many many things, some more questionable than others, I found a solution that to me is clear and predictable.

I did several things.

-- I kept the views in landscape mode in IB.

-- I checked both landscape modes in the project settings  - there a four icons there to control it

-- Orientation mgmt has changed in iOS 6.x. I had to overwrite a few methods to support changing to landscape

this method is for iOS 5.x

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation & UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
}
```

these 2 methods are for iOS 6.x

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger supportedOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    return supportedOrientations;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

-- But the key was to change the logic in the AppDelegate. Original code I had there was adding a subview (controller.view) to the window. This stopped working in iOS 6.x - I changed the call to window.setRootController. That was the final step that sealed it - it would not work without making this final change

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{        
    //[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationController overrides the contain UIViewController orientation settings, so you have to create a custom subclass of UINavigationController with the following for 5.1:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[self topViewController] isKindOfClass:[SigCaptureViewController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
    }
}
```

For 6.0 and above you need:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([[self topViewController] isKindOfClass:[EXTRASigCaptureViewController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

What I haven't figured out is how to make the force the UINavigationController to rotate.   calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO]` causes the status bar to rotate but doesn't cause the view to rotate.