# How to force or disable interface orientation for some but not all UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, rotation

I have an app with 9-10 screens. I embedded a `UINavigationController` into my view controller. I have few view controllers which I want set only portrait orientation: it means that rotating the device should not rotate these view controllers to landscape mode. I have tried the following solutions:

**first:**

```
   NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

but screen still rotates to landscape.

**Second:**
I created a custom view controller class as `PortraitViewController` and added the code below in `PortraitViewController.m`

```
@interface PortraitViewController ()
@end

@implementation PortraitViewController
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //Here check class name and then return type of orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
@end
```

After that I implemented `PortraitViewController.h` as a base class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PortraitViewController.h"
@interface Login : PortraitViewController
@end
```

It does not work at all, still allows view controller to rotate in landscape mode.

Is there any other solution i am using iOS 8 & don't want viewcontroller to rotate in landscape mode?

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to have Landscape orientation only for some view controllers, and force other view controllers orientation to stick to Portrait?

Comment: where have you written first two lines?

Comment: In ViewDidLoad@iAnurag

Comment: @JulianM posted the correct answer. You are, however, taking some risks with the coherence of your application, since the hidden view controllers will not receive orientation changes messages. You should consider redesigning your interface and fine tune your user experience,

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064900/how-do-i-force-a-specific-uiinterfaceorientation-on-an-individual-view-in-a-uina

Comment: @TechGuy did you still facing any problem

Comment: @Tech guy, Try this once.. In your appdelegates 
`- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window` method, check your controller and set the desired orientation. Also make sure you have the controller orientation methods set correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Try to subclass the `UINavigationController` you are using because the default `UINavigationController` is not forwarding the `shouldAutorotate` method to you viewcontroller.

Implement the following method in your `UINavigationController` subclass

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
```

Now the `UINavigationController` forwards the method call to its current visible `UIViewController` so you need to implement `shouldAutorotate` there individually to get your desired effect.

Answer (score 5):

Your PortraitViewController is ok and I don't know your Storyboard configuration. In your case important thing is you should embedded your target view controller in another new navigation controller, then set it's class to your PortraitViewController and present that navigation modally, like I have done in below image and it's working as expected.

[image]

[If you want to show animation that will make presentation animation like push animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999953/animate-presentmodalviewcontroller-from-right-left)

Below is mine PortrateNavigation subClass of UINavigationController

PortrateNavigation.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PortrateNavigation : UINavigationController

@end
```

PortrateNavigation.m

```
#import "PortrateNavigation.h"

@implementation PortrateNavigation

- (void)viewDidLoad  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this method along with `shouldAutorotate`  and `supportedInterfaceOrientations`

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    //Setting the orientation of the view.  I've set it to portrait here.
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

}
```

Also you can use this `[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]` So that it rotates to the desired new orientation

Answer (score 3):

Create a category on the `UINavigationController` and override `supportedInterfaceOrientations`

```
#import "UINavigationController+Orientation.h"

 @implementation UINavigationController (Orientation)

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
    return YES;
 }

@end
```

When you Embedded `UINavigationController`, Containers don't ask their children whether to rotate or not

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually. All view controllers, in those you do not want to rotate view, implement following method.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Do i need to set some delegate for using this method?

Comment: No need to set delegate, it's `UIViewController` class method.

Comment: If the view is embed in a uinavigation controller you should subclass the navigation and in your custom navigation controller write that code

Answer (score 1):

Tr this in your view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait |
           UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Make a bool variable in your AppDelegate.

2) Then copy & paste below code in AppDelegate.m (modify it as per your requirement)

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{NSLog(@"%d", [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)

if (self.isLandscape == YES) //bool created in first step
{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

3) Now copy & paste below code in the viewWillAppear method of the view controller for which you want to force orientation.

```
[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].isLandscape = YES; //bool created in first step
 NSNumber *value1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]; //change the orientation as per your requirement
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value1 forKey:@"orientation"];
```

4) Now before pushing this view controller, you need to set the bool first. So, let's say you want to push ABC view controller

```
[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].isLandscape = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:<ABC view controller instance> animated:NO];
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Shouldn't the return type of 'supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:' be 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' instead of 'NSUInteger'?

Comment: @CharlieScott-Skinner Yes. You can write it there. But as the definition suggests 'typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIInterfaceOrientationMask)' you can also type NSUInteger.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Here is the link to the topic:
http://koreyhinton.com/blog/lock-screen-rotation-in-ios8.html

Comment: A short explanation would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to temporarily disable automatic rotation, avoid manipulating the orientation masks to do this. Instead, override the shouldAutorotate method on the initial view controller. This method is called before performing any autorotation. If it returns NO, then the rotation is suppressed.

So you need to subclass 'UINavigationController', implement shouldAutorotate and use your navigation controller class in your storyboard.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate

{

id currentViewController = self.topViewController;


 if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]])
    return NO;

return YES;
```

}

an alternate approach can be found on

http://www.sebastianborggrewe.de/only-make-one-single-view-controller-rotate/