# Swift 3 how to lock orientation

Tags: swift, swift3, orientation

I am trying to lock my `viewController` to just portrait orientation without having to rely on Deployment Info but my following code isn't working

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}

 override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Comment: why not rely on that info? it's not a good way to try to be smarter than xcode

Comment: I copied and paste your code and it does lock the viewController to *portrait* mode, `override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait }` should be enough for your case.

Comment: @Carlo plz have a look here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758706/how-to-force-or-disable-interface-orientation-for-some-but-not-all-uiviewcontrol/31801804#31801804

Answer (score 6):

You can try this in the AppDelegate. This will lock the orientation for all your viewControllers

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put your code in parent view Controller otherwise it may not work, for example, in the navigation controller view controller class.