# How to navigate back to a previous view hierarchy using navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I started with `NavCntlr -> ViewA -> ViewB -> ViewC`

But now I have `NavCntlr -> ViewA -> ViewB -> CustomNavCntlr -> ViewC`

(If curious, CustomNavController forces portrait orientation using the technique found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31801804/814186)

So, the navigation bar on ViewB has a 'Back to ViewA' button. But after introducing CustomNavCntlr, ViewC does not have a 'Back to ViewB'.

The question: **How can I navigate from ViewC to ViewB similar to (from the user's perspective) how I navigate from ViewB to ViewA?**

If it helps, ViewC is presented with

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueToViewC" sender: self];`

And the segue is a Push (though I may use Present Modally since that was the suggestion in the example linked above).

Comment: Can you show the code used to present the viewB please? also what is your exact question is how to perform a pop in you viewcontroller stack? or how to add a button to your navigation bar to perform some selector?

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic I clarified a bit. Thanks for any help.